# How to Add a CountDown Timer inside a jQuery Dialog Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, dialog, countdown

I was trying to figure out how to add a countdown inside of a buttons text for the jQuery UI Dialog, and was unable to find anything.  After some time, I coded a solution to the problem.

Comment: There really is no question here. It's more like "look at what I've done". It's certainly helpful but it doesn't fit the Q and A model.

Answer (score 2):

Below is the code to do so:

```
function jqAlert(message, time) {
            var counter = time;
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
               title: "Message From Web App",
               modal: true,
               resizable: true,
               autoOpen: true, 
               modal: true,
               buttons: {
                    "OK": {
                        text: "OK (" + (time / 1000)+ ")" ,
                        id: "btnDialogOK",
                        click: function(){
                            $('#dialog').dialog('close');
                        }
                    }
               },
               open: function(event, ui) {
                    countdown(time);
                    $(this).html(message);
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $('#dialog').dialog('close');                
                    }, time);
                }
            });
         } 
         function countdown(time) {
            var timeleft = (time / 1000);
            var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
            timeleft--;
            document.getElementById("btnDialogOK").style.padding = "7px 18px 7px 18px";
            document.getElementById("btnDialogOK").textContent = "OK " + "(" + timeleft + ")";
            if(timeleft &lt;= 0)
                clearInterval(downloadTimer);
            },1000);      
         }
```

To call the jqAlert method from within the onclick:

```
jqAlert("This is an Alert", 5000);
```

Comment: Really??? Whats your question? Why are you asking, if you already have an answer?

Comment: I think this was supposed to be a tutorial.